# Editable Table in Flask/HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to create an excel-like table to update and log things on the go.

I have found this javascript:

```
function init()
{
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("editabletable");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
    {
        makeTableEditable(tables[i]);
    }
}

function makeTableEditable(table)
{
    var rows = table.rows;
    var r;
    for (r = 0; r < rows.length; r++)
    {
        var cols = rows[r].cells;
        var c;
        for (c = 0; c < cols.length; c++)
        {
            var cell = cols[c];
            var listener = makeEditListener(table, r, c);
            cell.addEventListener("input", listener, false);
        }
    }
}

function makeEditListener(table, row, col)
{
    return function(event)
    {
        var cell = getCellElement(table, row, col);
        var text = cell.innerHTML.replace(/<br>$/, '');
        var items = split(text);

        if (items.length === 1)
        {
            // Text is a single element, so do nothing.
            // Without this each keypress resets the focus.
            return;
        }

        var i;
        var r = row;
        var c = col;
        for (i = 0; i < items.length && r < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
            cell = getCellElement(table, r, c);
            cell.innerHTML = items[i]; // doesn't escape HTML

            c++;
            if (c === table.rows[r].cells.length)
            {
                r++;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
        cell.focus();
    };
}

function getCellElement(table, row, col)
{
    // assume each cell contains a div with the text
    return table.rows[row].cells[col].firstChild;
}

function split(str)
{
    // use comma and whitespace as delimiters
    return str.split(/,|\s|<br>/);
}

window.onload = init;
```

And it seems like it will work well in saving and keeping the edits in the table.

The issue is, however, that I am using pycharms and - unfortunately - cannot use a js file within mine.

Is there a way to convert this to Python, or a way to code a table within Python?

Comment: I don't understand what Pycharm has to do with anything; that's just an editor. And no, if you want iteractivity in the front end in a web application you need Javascript.

Comment: pycharm requires you to pay to use .js files

Comment: That sounds unlikely. But even if it does, you could just use one of the other thousands of open-source editors out there.

Comment: true, but i like pycharms :(! Anyway, this was sort of what i was expecting, so thanks !